# Extracting data with python from json

Tags: python, json, excel, parsing

I'm pretty noob at python and json and first of all idk if it is possible to do what I want to do.

I have a very nested json file, something like that:

```
{
"project": {
    "project_name" :"name"
}

"positions": {
    "file": {
        "name": "name",
        "analysis": {
            "components": {
                "first_component": {
                    "modes":{
                        "mode_1",
                        "type":{
                            "loads":{
                                "load_type": {
                                    "value": 111111
                                }
                            }
                            "design_value": 111111
                        }
                    }       
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The json file is more complex, I have only shown you one value of one kind of load.
What I want to extract is the name that appears in `"first_component"` , `"type"` , `"load_type"`, `"value"` and `"design_value"`.

When I'll get that values the idea is to put it in an Excel file. So the python code would work as a "filter".

I'm not asking for a piece of code that do the job, it would be unfair. I'm asking for a way to face it, what I should learn, any advice will be welcome.

Thank you so much! .

Comment: Have a look how to work with general dictionaries in Python, json is in some way only multileveled dictionary

Comment: If you are parsing a json file with python, what does the `excel` tag have to do with this?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is a notation for expressing a JavaScript object as a string.

When you parse a JSON string in Python, you get an object of type `dict` - a dictionary.

So I would suggest you read up about dictionaries and their indexing methods...

To get you going, just consider the following:

```
>>> d = {'another_dict': {3: 4, 'one_more': {7: 7, 'dog': 'woof'}}, 'cat': 'meow'}
>>> d['another_dict']
{3: 4, 'one_more': {7: 7, 'dog': 'woof'}}
>>> d['another_dict'][3]
4
>>> d['another_dict']['one_more']
{7: 7, 'dog': 'woof'}
>>> d['another_dict']['one_more']['dog']
'woof'
>>> d['cat']
'meow'
```

And in terms of loading in the JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> d = json.loads('{"cat": "meow"}')
>>> d
{'cat': 'meow'}
```